# Intrinsic content size of UILabel with NSAttributedString and indentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Why does setting an indent on the paragraph style attribute not have an affect on a `UILabel` using `NSAttributedString`?

For example:

```
  NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
  paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 50;
  NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
                               NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                               };
  NSString *string = @"some string";
  self.label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                              attributes:attributes];
```

UILabel with indentation (green background set to see the label size):

[image: label with indentation]

UILabel without indentation (green background set to see the label size):

[image: label without indentation]

Comment: I had same situation (wanted to add indents to the label from left and right). Paragraph style do not work they way we want. However you can wrap label inside other `UIView` and add needed spaces.